# Lazy loading of heightForRowAtIndexPath in UITableView with many rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` with many rows(+1000). I get the rows of these `UITableView` once by using `NSFetchedResultsController` and `fetchBatchSize`  in `viewDidLoad` as below:

```
@interface MessagesViewController ()  
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *messagesFRC;
@end



@implementation MessagesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.messagesFRC == nil) {

        // Read in Model.xcdatamodeld
        NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc =
        [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

        // Where does the SQLite file go?
        NSArray *documentDirectories =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                            YES);
        // Get one and only document directory from that list
        NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];
        NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"model.sqlite"];

        NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:nil
                                         URL:storeURL
                                     options:nil
                                       error:&error]) {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"OpenFailure"
                                           reason:[error localizedDescription]
                                         userInfo:nil];
        }

        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSString *entityName = @"Message";
        NSString *sortAttribute = @"timestamp";


        NSEntityDescription *e = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context];

        request.entity = e;


        NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor
                                sortDescriptorWithKey:sortAttribute
                                ascending:NO];
        request.sortDescriptors = @[sd];

//        request.fetchLimit = 30;
        request.fetchBatchSize = 60;


        self.messagesFRC = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];


        NSError *error3 = nil;
        if (![self.messagesFRC performFetch:&error3]) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        self.messagesFRC.delegate = self;
    }
}

@end
```

Also I set the height of each cells with `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in this controller:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView]) {
        NSManagedObject *row = [self.messagesFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *messageText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[row valueForKey:@"text"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        messageText = [[GeneralHelper convertHtmlToString:messageText] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
        //        messageText = @"yes\r\nnew";

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        //        paragraphStyle.


        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: self.messageFont,
                                     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}; // TODO: Font


        CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame)-kMessageTableViewCellAvatarHeight;
        width -= 25.0;

        CGRect titleBounds = [[row valueForKey:@"title"] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:NULL];
        CGRect bodyBounds = [messageText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:NULL];

        if (messageText.length == 0) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(titleBounds);
        height += CGRectGetHeight(bodyBounds);
        height += 40.0;

        if (height < kMessageTableViewCellMinimumHeight) {
            height = kMessageTableViewCellMinimumHeight;
        }

        return height;
    }
    else {
        return kMessageTableViewCellMinimumHeight;
    }
}
```

The problem is that loading the UITableView taking a long time (more than 15 seconds) because of setting height of all cells at the beginning of workflow. So I need lazy loading on `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for each 30 cells, and then by scrolling up and down, get the next 30 cells height.

In addition, I check the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for iOS 7+, but it had very high CPU usage:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can try using `- tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Please read it again, in the last part of question I mentioned it.

Comment: Also, the table view only loads the visible cells, so it's only going to call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for those.  If you log or set a breakpoint, you can see this for yourself.

Comment: @Avi +1000 logs for heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You should not return `...AutomaticDimension` for the estimated height. You should return the estimated height. So `return 100;` for instance. You should try profiling the app with the automatic dimension and seeing **WHY** it is using a lot of CPU. Have you created your cells properly with auto layout constraints from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter say numberOfRenderedRows. numberOfRenderedRows is set to 30 in start and that will be the added by 30 everytime user will scroll the table and refreshes. This will be count of the tableview rows. Use following to add refreshing control.

## #

```
UIRefreshControl* refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(actionRefreshRows) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Comment: Could you please explain it more ? Some examples or documentation? Where to use it exactly ? Thanks

Comment: Check following links for explanation of UIRefreshControl               ##         http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-uirefreshcontrol--mobile-14712              ##              https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to make your cells **self sizing**.

By setting proper constraints to your prototype cell, you can get rid of your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

[The documentation is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html).

Comment: Good way and works (initial time reduces significantly), However it causes high CPU load when scrolling fast